# Rails 3.0, want to match 'UK' == 'United Kingdom' in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, attributes, custom-attribute

I have a problem,
I have a Country model. where the entry in the DB is: `{:name => 'United Kingdom'}`

The data I have is `UK` instead of `United Kingdom`. in the other models where i search for it i have done:

```
country_name = "United Kingdom" if country.name == "UK"
```

but i have to do this all over the application and that is just bad.

So the question: How can I, in the `Country` model, do a search that ONLY does it for search. when it makes a query, I don't want `{:name => 'UK'}`.

eg. if I search for `UK` and the result should turn out `{:name => 'United Kingdom'}` NOT `{:name => 'UK'}`.

The solution is ok if I can just put some stupid hack in like:

```
name = "United Kingdom" if searchstring == "UK"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a customer finder method to your `Country` model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.by_name(name)
    name == 'UK'? find_by_name('United Kingdom') : find_by_name(name)
  end
end
```

Then you can use `Country.by_name('...')` whenever you need to find a country by its name. Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the semantics of the `find_by_name` method:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_name(name)
    name = 'United Kingdom' if name == 'UK'
    where(:name => name)
  end
end
```

There are various variations around this. I think I would favour the second example because it presents the same API as the dynamic attribute-based finders that ActiveRecord provides i.e. `find_by_XXX` etc.

Comment: is it possible to make it generic, so for all searches called with the `where(:name => 'UK')` it would work?

Comment: @raus22 I don't believe that's possible without monkey-patching ActiveRecord itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think ill do the custom `Country.by_name` method

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with some fairly nasty monkey patching of the ActiveRecord::Base.find method, but I don't think that is a good idea.

Where does the string 'UK' come from? User input?

I would suggest wherever that source is, put it through a common filter (perhaps an application_helper method) that converts 'UK' to "United Kingdom'.